# Not working: require('react/addons')

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I'm using ReactJS & Browserify. I can't figure out why this `require` doesn't give me access to `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`:

```
    var React = require('react/addons');
```

I tried adding this and it's still not working:

```
    var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.ReactCSSTransitionGroup;
```

To get it working I had to add:

```
    var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require("react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup");
```

How can I gain access to all `addons` through: `require('react/addons')` ?

Answer (score 3):

Requiring 'react/addons' simply adds the addons object to React and exports React.

```
React.addons = {
  CSSTransitionGroup: ReactCSSTransitionGroup,
  LinkedStateMixin: LinkedStateMixin,
  ...

module.exports = React;
```

As in the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) you can find the animation addon at `React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup`.

Side note: requiring 'react' and 'react/addons' doesn't include react twice.  Some people have asked about that in the past, so I just want to clarify.

Comment: In the 0.14 version of React you'll get a warning from `require('react/addons')` - use `var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');` instead